# Error in SSIS loading form Excel (2007) - Error: Opening a rowset for "Sheet1$" failed & VS_ISBROKEN

Tags: excel, ssis

The SSIS Package is loading Excel 2007 file using the MS Access OLEDB driver.

**ERROR MESSAGE**
Opening a rowset for "Sheet1$" failed. Check that the object exists in the database.
EX_SRC - Excel Generic file source using OLE connector failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".
SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
There were errors during task validation.

**Error description**
The Excel spreadsheet loads fine on the desktop in SSIS. It has been deployed to run through the SSIS catalog on the server using Active Batch as the scheduler. On the Test environment this also works ok. The error only occurs when running the package from the Production server.

**Trouble shooting**

1. The VS_ISBROKEN message normally indicates a metadata issue i.e. a column type has changed or a column is missing etc. To correct this you'd open up the the Data Flow task in SSIS reading from the affected spreadsheet and correct the issue or refresh the metadata. However when I do this in SSIS there are no errors reported, so nothing to fix or refresh.
2. Ensured that my desktop, the Test server & Production have the same driver version, same regional settings.
3. Thought the date column might be treated differently on the Production server which is causing the metadata "VS_ISBROKEN" error. As above checked that the regional settings on the Production server is the same as my desktop and get no errors locally.
4. Can't get SSIS installed on the Production to test it locally on the server.
5. I have a similar package loading an Excel 2007 format successfully, which rules out an issue with the driver not working correctly.
6. 64bit is set to true as this is not using the Excel connection.

Any suggestions to further troubleshoot the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trying just about everything I could think of I kept coming back to this one post: [Post describing rights access for buffer](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1680961-364-2.aspx) 
The account which the scheduling tool was running under did not have write access to the C drive on the SSIS server. Although the spreadsheet was only 5 columns by 30 000 rows it appeared SSIS needed to write the buffer to the C drive. During the debugging of this issue I tested it by running the job with only 5 rows which worked successfully. The problem was resolved and ran successfully after granting the scheduling account write access to the C drive.

Comment: Hi, can you please tell me what is the specific place (folder) that the user need access?, because in my job dont want bring me all C drive access... . i will apprecciate your answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I granted access to the batch account to the full C drive as the batch account is regarded as a systems admin. I'll dig to see if I have notes on this for the specific folder.

Comment: Thank you for fast answer, in my case i was need to grant access to Default user folder, thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In SSIS design mode, the path & file variable should be set in value field not expression field, else scheduling software like Active Batch will not be able to replace the value